# Subprocess stdout: remove unnecessary char

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I´m using the subprocess module and it works fine, the only thing is that the stdout returns a value "**b'**" or in some cases longer text like "**user config - ignore ...**". Is it possible to remove this first part of the stdout without using str.substring() or similar methodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output = subprocess.run(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

in the abrove example the std.out.decode() function could be used and it will be saved as < str >

```
decoded_output = nodes.stdout.decode()
```

And if some type of commands support json output(for example pvesh in proxmox) you could use the string and load it as json.

```
json_output = json.loads(decoded_output)
```